# For-loop and storing results in an array in R

Tags: r, for-loop

Let say I’ve a data frame consists of one variable (x)

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,3,5,6,7,8,9,9,4,4))
```

I want to know how many numbers are less than 2,3,4,5,6,7.
I know how to do this manually using

```
# This will tell you how many numbers in df less than 4
xnew <- length(df[ which(df$x < 4), ])
```

My question is how can I automate this by using for-loop or other method(s)? And I need to store the results in an array as follows

```
i   length
2   1
3   2
4   4
5   6
6   7
7   8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to loop over (`sapply`) the numbers (`2:7`), check which elements in `df$x` is less than (`<`) the "number" and do the `sum`, `cbind` with the numbers, will give the `matrix` output

```
res <- cbind(i=2:7, length=sapply(2:7, function(y) sum(df$x <y)))
```

Or you can vectorize by creating a `matrix` of numbers (`2:7`) with each number replicated by the number of rows of `df`, do the logical operation `<` with `df$x`.  The logical operation is repeated for each column of the matrix, and get the column sums using `colSums`.

```
 length <-  colSums(df$x <matrix(2:7, nrow=nrow(df), ncol=6, byrow=TRUE))

 #or
 #length <- colSums(df$x < `dim<-`(rep(2:7,each=nrow(df)),c(12,6)))
 cbind(i=2:7, length=length)
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I store i, too? i = 2,3,4,5,6,7.

Answer (score 1):

```
num = c(2,3,4,5,6,7)
res = sapply(num, function(u) length(df$x[df$x < u]))

data.frame(number=num, 
           numberBelow=res)
```

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized solution:

```
findInterval(2:7*(1-.Machine$double.eps),sort(df$x))
```

The `.Machine$double.eps` part assure that you are taking just the numbers lower than and not lower or equal than.